# C# How to add forward slash in enum

Tags: c#

I have an enum in my C# class.

```
public enum OutputFormat {
      DOCX = 0,
      PDF = 1,
      @out/pdf = 2
  }
```

How to add out/pdf in it? Thanks

Comment: you cannot, as (for example) you cannot start a variable name with numbers or use "void" as variable name ... There are some language / compiler restriction

Comment: You can't an why would you want to?

Comment: @Othello.netdev You can use keywords as variable names, if you prefix them with `@`.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx).

Comment: The thing is..Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Gabriel Negut, Adding a @ in front of a reserved word transform it in a Non reserved word... (_ it's run well as every other valid char)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not possible for an enum to contain a "/", you could implement your own Enum.ConvertToString() extension method if the you are specifically looking to for the "out/pdf" format.

The Enum Extension Method class:

```
using System;

namespace TestConsole
{
    public static class OutputFormatEnum
    {
        public enum OutputFormat
        {
            DOCX = 0,
            PDF = 1,
            outpdf = 2 //@out/pdf
        }

        public static String ConvertToString(this OutputFormat outputFormat)
        {
            return (outputFormat == OutputFormat.outpdf) ? "out/pdf" : Enum.GetName(outputFormat.GetType(), outputFormat);
        }

        public static OutputFormat ConverToEnum(this string enumValue)
        {
            OutputFormat outputFormat;
            if (!Enum.TryParse(enumValue, true, out outputFormat))
            {
                if (enumValue.Equals("out/pdf", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    outputFormat = OutputFormat.outpdf;
                else
                    throw new InvalidCastException($"'{enumValue}' is not a valid value for enum OutputFormat");
            }

            return outputFormat;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using System;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string outputFormat = "out/pdf";
            var outputFormatEnum = outputFormat.ConverToEnum();
            var outputFormatEnumValueString = outputFormatEnum.ConvertToString();

            Console.WriteLine($"outputFormat: {outputFormat} | outputFormatEnumValueString: {outputFormatEnumValueString}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Console Output]

Comment: This needs to be linked into those Enum as a string instead of int questions that come up from time to time. (At least where having a collection of consts causes enumeration issues)

Answer (score 4):

[Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) values can only be integral types (byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong). Enum names can only be valid [.NET identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx) => no `/` possible.

Comment: ok thank you. Many people asking why you want this instead of answering question

Answer (score 2):

Technically, no, you can't due to `/`.

[C# specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) "1.10 Enums":

> An enum type is a distinct value type with a set of named constants.

Exact rules for constant naming can be found from spec "2.4.2 Identifiers".

Also, if the exact name is more important to you than the enum value then you should use string constants instead and avoid possible bugs when another developer choses to refactor those names to remove unorthodox characters (incl that ugly-looking `@`-prefix).

For example look at how MS chose to implement `MediaTypeNames`:

```
public static class MediaTypeNames
{
    public static class Application
    {
        public const string Octet = "application/octet-stream";
        public const string Pdf = "application/pdf";
        public const string Rtf = "application/rtf";
        public const string Soap = "application/soap+xml";
        public const string Zip = "application/zip";
    }
    //omitted rest..
}
```